# How do I prevent the white outline around the inside of the blue circle not happen?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing, digital

[image]

when I use the fill option in photoshop it leaves an edge of ugly white border between the black outline and the blue. is there a way to fix this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the black stroke using anti-aliasing to make the edges appear smoother. Anti-aliasing is the smoothing of jagged edges in digital images by averaging the colors of the pixels at a boundary. So when you make a selection, it stops short of selecting the darker pixels.

[image: anti-aliasing image]

One method to fill the shape.

1. Use the magic wand tool to select the inside of the circle.
2. Go to Select -> Modify -> Expand
3. Expand by 2 pixels.
4. Make a new layer, and fill the selection with a color, put that layer below the black stroke layer.

Comment: thank you so much this method worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the tolerance of the Bucket Fill Tool in the tool options along the. Try a setting such as 100

[image]

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Does this only work if the black stroke is painted on a white background? I couldn't get the same result if the black stroke is painted on a transparent layer and then filled with a color.

Comment: @AndrewH  I did paint the black stroke directly on a white background (all on one layer) in my example. Yes, it doesn't work so well if you are trying to fill a transparent layer, however if you make a white background layer underneath, then it works just fine.

Comment: This was also very helpful thank you